# Can pheophytin be converted back to chlorophyll?

Tags: redox

Some fossil leaves are "greenish" when first exposed but rapidly darken to an "olive brown" color when they come into contact with air. If the fossil leaf contains pheophytin, can the addition of magnesium ions to an extract of the fossil change the pheophytin back to chlorophyll?

Comment: What is a fossil leaf, exactly?

Comment: Well, according to the Wikipedia pheophytin can be produced by treating chlorophyll with a weak acid. The question is then whether that reaction is reversible.